# Drools Server fails starting when reading brl rules from Guvnor

Tags: drools, guvnor

I'm having trouble with the integration of Drools Camel Server and Guvnor.. Version 5.5.0

I've created a JAR which contains POJO and used it in Guvnor to create a BRL rule (in the future will be created by not technical people)..

The problem is that when I start the drools server , it complains that it cannot find the class Message defined in the Import of the Rules..

Below the configuration of the Knowledge-servics.xml

```
    <drools:grid-node id="node1" />
    <drools:resource-change-scanner id="res-scanner1" interval="15" enabled="true" />
    <drools:kbase id="kbase1" node="node1" />
    <drools:kagent id="kagent1" kbase="kbase1" new-instance="false">
            <drools:resources>
                    <drools:resource type="PKG" source="http://localhost:8082/guvnor/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/package/<mypackage>/LATEST" basic-authentication="enabled" username="admin" 
                            password="admin" /> 
            </drools:resources>
    </drools:kagent>
    <drools:ksession id="ksession1" type="stateless" kbase="kbase1" node="node1" />
```

This is my rule in Guvnor

```
package mypackage 

import mypackage.model.Message 
rule "first" 
dialect "mvel" 
when 
   Message( text == "a" ) 
then 
   Message fact0 = new Message(); 
   fact0.setText( "b" ); 
   insert( fact0 ); 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The binary package doesn't contain the java classes. You have 2 options:
1.- Copy your POJO jar in drools-server classpath
2.- You can programatically get the jar from Guvnor (Guvnor exposes it through an url) and add it to your classpath.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Yep, I copied the jar in the drools-server classpath.. I didn't know the other option, thanks!